# Disable image thumbnails for only one upload folder

Tags: uploads, thumbnails

I have a form that is uploading resumé files into a custom folder at /wp-content/uploads/resumes.

While I do want thumbnail sizes generated for the regular folders, I DO NOT want sizes generated for /wp-content/uploads/resumes.

Is this possible?

Comment: Related question with a plugin recommendation: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53344/how-to-generate-thumbnails-when-needed-only